# Listen to websocket with auth and certificate in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, websocket

I was looking ideally for a native way in kotlin on windows to create a websocket client/listener, but that doesn't seem to be possible so I've decided to use the ktor library instead. At the beginning of the program, I load a certificate file by the name `riotgames.pem` to perform GET requests to an API, and that works completely fine:

```kotlin
fun initalize_certificate() {
    val certificate_file = File("riotgames.pem")
    val certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509")
    val certificate = certificateFactory.generateCertificate(certificate_file.inputStream())

    val keyStore = java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(java.security.KeyStore.getDefaultType())
    keyStore.load(null, null)
    keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", certificate)

    val trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm())
    trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore)

    ssl_context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")
    ssl_context.init(null, trustManagerFactory.trustManagers, null)
}
```

This exposes `ssl_context` as a global variable to be used later in the requests. However, I now want to listen to a websocket server with the same certificate, and I can't seem to find a way to do so. This is my starter code (`port` and `auth` are specified elsewhere and the same values work to obtain get requests):

```kotlin
val client = HttpClient {
    install(WebSockets)
}
runBlocking {
    client.wss(
        method = HttpMethod.Get,
        host = "127.0.0.1",
        port = port.toInt(),
        request = {
            header("Authorization", "Basic $auth")
        }
    ) {
        while(true) {
            println(incoming.receive().readBytes())
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried creating a CIO HttpClient and passing in the trustManagerFactory from the certificate initialization code into the https settings, but doesn't seem to have worked.

My main questions is how would I use this certificate in my websocket connection? I also have some secondary questions: What's the difference between `client.wss()` and `client.webSocket()`? Do I need to specify `"wss://127.0.0.1"` or is that implied? [This article](https://hextechdocs.dev/getting-started-with-the-lcu-websocket/) mentions that the websocket I'm looking at uses the WAMP protocol but it doesn't seem to be one of the options in ktor, is there a way to emulate it? How would I send data back to the server?